# UITextField failing to provide indicator

Tags: ios, uitextfield

When a user taps on a textfield, normally a flashing indicator shows that they are typing in that iOS UITextField. However, on this view controller it doesn't. Oddly enough though, when I use that same code on a different view controller, it does appear.

```
@interface MainViewController ()
{
        UITextField *fldye;
}

  fldye = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 180, 140, 25)];
    fldye.placeholder = @"Year";
    fldye.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [fldye setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [fldye.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [fldye.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [fldye setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    fldye.TextAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    NSUserDefaults *defaujetzb = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *labsterzb = [defaujetzb objectForKey:@"mypreviousaddedyear"];
    fldye.text = labsterzb;
```

These are the libraries I am adding...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "Cellmain.h"
#import "Celleventmain.h" //I have two tableviews present on this controller as opposed to others
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>

#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ADBannerViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the tint color was conflicting with something else strangely enough. I was able to manually bypass it though.

```
[fldye setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```